# How to early bind COM objects in AutoIt?

Tags: com, autoit, early-binding

A colleague of mine claims that you cannot early-bind COM objects in AutoIt. Is this true?

Comment: AutoIt is an interpreted language, so binding is probably done when you call ObjGet or ObjCreate (don't take my word for it though, you'll need to ask [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/forum/7-developer-chat/) for that kind of information). When you say 'early' do you mean when the object is declared or when a property/method is used?

Comment: I am a VB programmer so I mean early as you have to add a reference to the library and then declare Dim a as MyLibrary.MyClass etc.

Comment: I've reposted [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/128342-early-binding/), that should get an answer soon. In answer to your last comment... No you can't add references. Everything is done at runtime

Comment: What I want is that a spelling mistake in a method name call is picked up at compile time - rather than 2 months down the line when it is called for the first time and an error is thrown (as happened today!) - Sounds like this isn't possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoIt is an interpreted language even when compiled. The actual process of compiling is simply embedding the code in the interpreter (with some preprocessor elements sorted out like includes).

As a result, binding can not be done at compile time, as there is no compile time. This means that the following will compile fine and no error will be detected.

```
$oShell = ObjCreate("shell.application")
If False Then ConsoleWrite($oShell.LolWut & @LF)
```

Run that and nothing will happen. $oShell.LolWut will never be evaluated and so there is no error. Try it with the if test executing the statement and you get: The requested action with this object has failed.

Edit: Also note the reply [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/128342-early-binding/page__view__findpost__p__890487) for more details on implementation.